# Extracting feature importances along with column names from sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I have a sklearn pipeline with two steps (a columntransformer preprocessor with a One hot encoder and a randomforestregressor estimator). I would like to get the feature names of the encoded columns after One hot encoding. My pipeline looks like this.

> categorical_preprocessor = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore")

```
# Model processor
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    [('categorical', categorical_preprocessor, categorical_columns)], remainder="passthrough")

est = RandomForestRegressor(
n_estimators=100, random_state=0)

pipe = make_pipeline(preprocessor,est)
```

I am trying to get the feature names of the encoded columns like this:

> pipe['preprocessor'].transformers[0][0].get_feature_names(categorical_columns)

But I get an error.

> 'str' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names'

Comment: The error is because `pipe['preprocessor'].transformers[0]` is the tuple `('categorical', categorical_preprocessor, categorical_columns)`.  The 0th element of that tuple is the _name_ you've given the transformer, hence `'str' object` error.  Even using instead `[1]` would fail, because `transformers` is the unfitted object; you need `transformers_`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is apparantly a new feature from scikit-learn 1.0 where we extract the feature names as:

```
pipeline[:-1].get_feature_names_out()
```